# How to install Asymptote for Windows 10 (64 bit)?

Tags: asymptote

I installed Asymptote (program, not package) on my computer (64 bit, Windows 10 Home). It works quite well. However I realize that my Asymptote version is for Windows 32 bit.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote/files/2.49/

Is there Asymptote version for Windows 64 bit? I hope it (if any) will compile Asymptote more smooth and less annoying "black strips" error.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As with all TeX packages you should ideally only download via package manager thus MiKTeX will I think install its own compatible MiKTeX-version as required similar for TeX Live. if you are using a standalone version it should not matter unless it interferes with the TeX one

Comment: @KJO: I did not ask about asymptote package. I asked about Asymptote program version 64 bit for Windows 64 bit

Comment: Yes there is 64 bit setup https://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote/files/2.49/asymptote-2.49-setup.exe/download but I can't say if it would clear your black strips issue and speedwise your milage may vary dependant on underlying hardware home http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/ bugs https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+ looks like some issues depend on GS version

Comment: @ KJO: are you sure that asymptote-2.49-setup.exe is for Windows 64bit?

Comment: nothing to show it isn't  it runs on 64 bit win10 but no help about and -version is identical to the 32 bit both have same documentation about the x86_64 and i386 3.0.4 cygwin1.dll libraries so it suggests  but does not confirm there are two versions but remote calling from a 32bit machine the 32 bit runs and the non 32 bit says cant run check if you have 32 bit or 64 bit so I have to presume it is 64bit